# phone call before job application

Tags: applications, europe

I am an expat in Norway and applying for a student consultant position at a university. I am planning to call the contact person listed on the anouncement. Could I ask about when they expect to conduct the interviews and when they expect the position to start? Even though I am interested in knowing these info I am worried it is a bit too early.

Is there a point in asking questions relevant to the job in this initial phonecall? I am thinking about asking if it is newly established position or addition to the team and the possibility for training but not so many things about the tasks.

Comment: If the position is announced, that means that the contact person is accepting inquiries.

Answer (score 4):

There is no problem in asking relevant questions. It comes across well  if you sound interested. And most people are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Could I ask about when they expect to conduct the interviews and when they expect the position to start?

Of course you can.

> Is there a point in asking questions relevant to the job in this initial phonecall?

No, wait for an actual interview.

Comment: I would ask questions if they are relevant to whether you should apply at all or not, saves everyone time. I've seen extremely vague job openings advertised that needed clarification before applying.